# don't want to show softkeyboard when clicked a textbox

Tags: android, android-webview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

I'm using the android webview. When I clicked on a textbox, the soft keyboard is showing is there any way to remove that behavior? Thanks a lot!

Comment: check [this][1] 

Hope it should helps you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard

Comment: There are ways to disable it, but how will you enter values there if your app is tested on a real time device?

Comment: thanks for the responses, i'm using something like html/js keyboard...